# another Haskell cardguess game

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a card guess game, this game has 3 target cards, and each time player selects 3 cards to be their guess. After that, player will receive a 3 integer feedback to this guess as a triple of correct cards, suits, and ranks, and return a pair of the next guess and game state

Until now, I have defined my own type of cards. Codes are shown below

```
data Suit = Club | Diamond | Heart | Spade
      deriving (Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum, Show)


data Rank =
    R2 | R3 | R4 | R5 | R6 | R7 | R8 | R9 | R10 |
    Jack | Queen | King | Ace
        deriving (Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum, Show)


data Card = Card {suit::Suit, rank::Rank}
          deriving (Eq, Bounded)

instance Ord Card where
    compare (Card s1 r1) (Card s2 r2) =
        let suitorder = compare s1 s2
        in  if suitorder == EQ then compare r1 r2 else suitorder

instance Enum Card where
    fromEnum (Card s r) = (fromEnum s)*13 + (fromEnum r)
    toEnum n = (Card s r)
      where s = toEnum (n `div` 13)
            r = toEnum (n `mod` 13)

instance Show Card where
    show (Card s r) = show r ++ show s


type GameState = [[Card]] -- store the remaining possible cards
```

now I need to write 2 function based on the requirement of question

```
initialGuess :: ([String],GameState)
```

which takes no input argument, and return a pair of an initial guess and a game state

```
nextGuess :: ([String],GameState) -> (Int,Int,Int) -> ([String],GameState)
```

takes as input a pair of the previous guess and game state, a feedback to this guess and a pair of the next guess and game state.

Now I have to convert [String] into type [Card] I defined, but I'm stuck with this transformation.

my current initialGuess are shown below

```
initialGuess::([String], GameState)
initialGuess = let guess = [(Card Club R2),(Card Club R3),(Card Club R4)]
                            gs = FilterGameState
                            in (guess, gs)
                            .....                 -not complete yet    

FilterGameState :: [[Card]]
FilterGameState = filter ([x,y,z]) decks
   where decks = [[x,y,z] | x <- [minBound..maxBound] :: [Card], 
                            y <- [minBound..maxBound] :: [Card],
                            z <- [minBound..maxBound] :: [Card]]
```

It is still hard for me to think a way to convert 'guess' in the initialGuess function to a string :( any more suggestions??

Comment: What kind of string are you passing in?

Comment: all [String] contain information about cards guessed. For example ["ClubR2","SpadeR3","HeartR5"], and I want to convert this to Card type, which is easy to be analysed in the following parts.

Comment: why do you want to have `initialGuess :: ([String],GameState)` instead of `initialGuess :: ([Card],GameState)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define Card to be instance of Read:

```
data Suit = Club | Diamond | Heart | Spade
      deriving (Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum, Show, Read)


data Rank =
    R2 | R3 | R4 | R5 | R6 | R7 | R8 | R9 | R10 |
    Jack | Queen | King | Ace
        deriving (Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum, Show, Read)


data Card = Card {suit::Suit, rank::Rank}
          deriving (Eq, Bounded)

instance Show Card where
  show (Card s1 r1) = show s1 ++ " " ++ show r1

instance Read Card where
  readsPrec i s = [(Card s1 r1, s'')
                  | (s1, s') <- readsPrec i s,
                    (r1, s'') <- readsPrec i s']

main = print $ (read "Club R3" :: Card)
```

(with a minor change in how you represent cards as strings).